# Two Modal box in Bootstrap

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using bootstrap 3.2.0.In this version, i want to show two dialog boxes.when i click the link in the page,first dialog box will be shown.after that click link on first dialog box second box will be shown.two dialog box will be shown and user can able to see. is it possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can use modal inside modal.

Take a look at this example  [Modal inside modal example](http://www.bootply.com/61322#)